# confirm user's input and show output then submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I would like to take a users form input,ask the user to confirm and show them their selection ,and then submit form to the server only after they have confirm.I am not really sure how to go about this?
Thanks,
Here is my code so far:

```
<form id="myform" action="form.php" method="post">
    <?php
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach($dir as $item) {
            $items = basename($item);
            $str = str_replace("+", " ", $items);
            if (strpos($str, 'test') === false) {
                if (strlen($str) == 3) {
                    $strs = ucwords(strtoupper($str));
                    echo "<li><label><input type = 'checkbox' class='check-class' name='chk[]' id='strs[]' value=$items>$strs</label></li>";
                } else {
                    $strs = ucwords($str);
                    echo "<li><label><input type='checkbox' class='check-class' name='chk[]' id='strs[]' value=$items>$strs</label></li>";
                }
            }
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    ?>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" style="font-face:'Comic Sams MS';font-size:larger;color:red;background-color:#FAF0E6;border:3pt ridge lightgrey;" value="Click to Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<div id="success"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#success').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form.php

```
<html>
<table>
<?php


       #$b = str_replace("+"," ",$_POST['chk']);
    #echo "<script type='text/javascript'> test() </script>";
    echo "You have selected these Folders";


    foreach($_POST['chk'] as  $val)
    { echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo str_replace("+"," ",$val);
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "</td>";
    }

?>
</table>    
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show on `form.php` ?

Comment: you can store form data into session variable for client confirmation and destroy those after clients confirmation.

Comment: I have added the form.php file

Comment: Have hidden fields on the form that records the state of 1a) brand new  1b)  unconfirmed.  And, 2) validationState: Failed or Success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    var selectedItemsText = '';
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
        selectedItemsText  += $(this).val() +'\r';
    });

    if(confirm('Are you sure? You've selected:\r'+selectedItemsText)){
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#success').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Check out this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/sor96vp3/) I've omitted the AJAX for obvious reasons.

There are nicer ways of doing this. You could use a [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) (or equivalent) for example. But for a quick, dirty, easy solutions - just use `confirm`.

Comment: Thanks@DaveSolomon this works but can I call the form.php in the if confirm code?

Comment: Yes - that's what the above should do :).
`confirm()` returns a boolean - true or false. So `if(confirm('abc?')){ success } else { failure }` will go to "success" if the user says "yes", or "failure" if the user chooses no/cancel.